# Two different objects in their tables to populate in collective object

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `tweet` and a `stream` table. I am populating these two tables into feed class rather than using one feed table. The problem is there is no unique `FeedId` that I am filling with `StreamId / TweetId` which can be same and I have to identify from `FeedTypeId` (Tweet, Post or Comment). I am not sure what I am doing is right, I wanted to get some opinion how these problem have had been handle better.

Thank you for your effort in advance.

Tables and Feed Class >

Tweets

```
[TweetId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TweetType] [smallint] NULL,
[SocialPageId] [int] NULL,
[SearchId] [int] NULL,
[TweetId] [bigint] NULL,
[Text] [varchar](255) NULL,
[UserID] [bigint] NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ScreenName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ProfileImageUrl] [varchar](255) NULL,
[IsFollowing] [bit] NULL,
[FollowersCount] [int] NULL,
[CreatedAt] [datetime] NULL,
[Created] [datetime] NULL,
[HasRead] [tinyint] NULL,
[IsRated] [tinyint] NULL,
[IsTasked] [tinyint] NULL,
```

Streams

```
[StreamId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SocialPageId] [varchar](200) NULL,
[TypeId] [int] NULL,
[TypeName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Text] [text] NULL,
[CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
[FBId] [varchar](100) NULL,
[FBUserId] [varchar](100) NULL,
[FBUserName] [varchar](100) NULL,
[FBImageLink] [varchar](250) NULL,
[ParentId] [varchar](100) NULL,
[HasRead] [tinyint] NULL,
[IsRated] [tinyint] NULL,
[IsTasked] [tinyint] NULL,
[Gender] [smallint] NULL

public class Feed
{
    public string FeedId { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public string FeedTypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string O_Id { get; set; }
    public string O_UserId { get; set; }
    public string O_UserName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string O_ImageLink { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public int Retweet { get; set; }
    public int Favorite { get; set; }
    public int Like { get; set; }
    public int Share { get; set; }
    public int IsTasked { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly post all the structures of all your table? And if there is a sample data much the better.

Comment: Yeah, sample data would be good.  Note that primary keys can be composed of multiple columns, if that would solve your problem (ie, the tuple (`FeedTypeId`, `StreamId/TweetId`) should be unique

Comment: I shared tables and feed class. yes I can make it unique with multiple columns, that's what I am doing right now. but It seems there should be better way to do this.